# Swift 3.0 filter function not working

Tags: ios, swift, filter, swift3

In Swift 2.2 I created a section index of my data with this code.

```
 func createSectionIndices(_ participants: List<Participant>){

        let array = participants.sorted(by: {$0.lastName.uppercased() < $1.lastName.uppercased()})

        sections = array
            .map({String($0.lastName.uppercased().characters.first!)})
            .enumerated()
            .filter({ $0 == 0 || !participants[$0 - 1].lastName.uppercased.hasPrefix($1) })
            .map({ (start,letter) in return
                (
                    index:  start,
                    length: participants.filter({$0.lastName.uppercased.hasPrefix(letter)}).count,
                    title:  letter
                )
            })
    }
```

Now with Swift 3.0 "Ambiguous reference to member '-'" in the line with the filter. `.filter({ $0 == 0 || !participants[$0 - 1].lastName.uppercased.hasPrefix($1) })`

How can this be fixed in Swift 3.0? Why is it ambiguous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is a bit misleading, `uppercased` has been changed to `uppercased()`